# Multiple image styles

Tags: 7, media

Is there a way to take multiple style image for one image field?
I want to use a 150×150, 180×180, and a 300×300 style at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly, you'll want to use the [ImageCache module](http://drupal.org/project/imagecache). This is in core as of Drupal 7. Try the [documentation for Drupal 6](http://drupal.org/node/163561) and/or [this screencast](http://blip.tv/file/256997) if you need help understanding how to use this module.

Comment: no its not like that.
first i use drupal 7
what i want to take 3 different style for image 
lets say
1- 150×150 (style A)
2- 180×180 (style C)
3- 300×300 (style D)
and i want these to happen to 1 image field without make 3 image fields and assign each one for one different style .
do u got me ?

Comment: @mohamad-salama that's how ImageCache works. You'll still have the one Field for images, there will just be multiple imagecache presets.

Answer (score 2):

You can manually call the image caches either in your template file or create them in [hook_preprocess_node(&$vars)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/7). You can get the image with [theme_image_style($vars)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--image--image.module/function/theme_image_style/7). There are some useful comments in the docs for theme_image_style.

Answer (score 1):

And once you've created the imagecache presets, they will then show up as field formatters for your teaser and node display settings as well as in views.